# Binding dereferenced null pointer to reference has undefined behavior Xcode 9

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode9

I am running Objective-C project on Xcode 9 and facing this error which states

EDIT: Using FBXSDK by AutoDesk. I think its related to clang version which is new in Xcode 9 (the project was written in Xcode 7). If I understand correctly I need to revert clang to older version from this [link](http://kuantinglai.blogspot.com/2017/09/setup-unreal-as-deep-reinforcement.html). Same problem when using Unreal Engine.

> Binding dereferenced null pointer to reference has undefined behavior

The script I am trying to run is the following

```
const FbxProperty& StaticInit(FbxObject* pObject, const char* pName, const FbxReference& pValue, bool pForceSet, FbxPropertyFlags::EFlags pFlags=FbxPropertyFlags::eNone)
{
    return StaticInit(pObject, pName, FbxGetDataTypeFromEnum(FbxTypeOf(*((FbxReference*)0))), pValue, pForceSet, pFlags);
}
```

StaticInit method

```
const FbxProperty& StaticInit(FbxObject* pObject, const char* pName, const FbxDataType& pDataType, const FbxReference& pValue, bool pForceSet, FbxPropertyFlags::EFlags pFlags=FbxPropertyFlags::eNone)
{
    bool lWasFound = false;
    *this = Create(pObject, pDataType, pName, "", true, &lWasFound);
    if( pForceSet || !lWasFound )
    {
        ModifyFlag(pFlags, true);   // modify the flags before we set the value
        Set(pValue);            // since we will trigger callbacks in there!
    }
    ModifyFlag(FbxPropertyFlags::eStatic, true);
    return *this;
}
```

Xcode underlying `*((FbxReference*)0` as an error.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGsms.png)

Comment: Dereferencing null is indeed undefined behavior — your code is doing the equivalent of `*nullptr`, which doesn't make sense. What does `ObjectTypeOf` do? If it depends on the value being passed in there, your program isn't well-formed.

Comment: @ItaiFerber yeah you are right, I will edit the code

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not much clearer. We'd need to know what `FbxTypeOf` does in order to figure out how to help you improve the code.

Comment: Its FBxSDK by AutoDesk

Comment: When asking for help, it's best to include _all_ of the information from your problem in the question instead of making others Google for it. In this case, it looks like `FbXTypeOf` is [defined here](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2017/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_fbxtexture_8h_html). Based on that, it looks like this usage is pretty nonsensical (on all fronts). You should be able to replace all of `FbxTypeOf(...)` with `eFbxEnum`, since [thats all this function ever returns](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/FBX-Developer-Help/cpp_ref/fbxtexture_8h_source.html#l00570).

Comment: It didn't solve the problem

Comment: What do you mean? Please update your code in the question with what you've got. It should read `return StaticInit(pObject, pName, FbxGetDataTypeFromEnum(eFbxEnum, pValue, pForceSet, pFlags);`

Comment: I think its related to clang version which is new in Xcode 9. If I understand correctly I need to revert clang to older version from this [link](http://kuantinglai.blogspot.com/2017/09/setup-unreal-as-deep-reinforcement.html). Same problem when using Unreal Engine. Do you have any ideas how to do that?

Comment: @ItaiFerber The project was built in Xcode 7 now I am trying to run it in Xcode 9

Comment: This code was completely incorrect in Xcode 7 as well — it is wrong in all versions of C++. The language itself specifies that dereferencing null is undefined behavior; this version of clang is only now warning on it. What is the issue with updating the code to remove the unnecessary dereference?

Comment: @ananai *Binding dereferenced null pointer to reference has undefined behavior* -- That is **not** a compiler error.  It is a warning that the later compiler's IDE has added *for your benefit*.  It is a feature it is now telling you of the potential issues -- there is no need to "downgrade" to any version of the compiler.  Just fix your code appropriately, and yes, it was wrong in any version of C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, thats what I want to do but I don't have an idea how to fix that.

Comment: @ananai -- Well I think you found a bug in the original code.  Might as well alert the authors to it so that they officially address the issue.  In addition, why not do what ItaiFerber suggested?

Comment: Yeah, I think I can fix it.

Answer (score -3):

Solved by changing 0 to 1.

```
return StaticInit(pObject, pName, FbxGetDataTypeFromEnum(FbxTypeOf(*((FbxReference*)1))), pValue, pForceSet, pFlags);
```